# Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

Android Studio displayed this error message when I added the following line to the build.gradle line to the dependencies: `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.parse.starter"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
        compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
        compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: Everything looks fine. Maybe your internet connection does not allowed to connect. Restart Android Studio and rebuild again. Check "offline work" is enabled or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See if you have jcenter() in your repositories in your project gradle.

For example:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {

        }

        ivy {

        }
    }
}
```